# select registers by condition on group

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say that I have one table with two columns `TYPE & COLOR` both columns can have repeat values, but I need to get one register for each values in the TYPE column and in the COLOR column get the value according to the hierarchy 1-blue, 2-green, 3-black, 4-red and the last 5-white. To explain myself better I have the table in the figure 1, and the result that I wan't is in the figure 2.

I can get the TYPE value using `MIN()` and `GROUP BY` but **how can I get the color value according to the hierarchy?**

[image]

Comment: Just to be sure, are you looking for a `SELECT` only everything starting at the tables' definition?

Comment: What would define the order of the type and the color?

Comment: Sorry, yes a `SELECT` is what I looking for

Comment: @LuisCazares for type column I just need to get one register for the same value, if I have five times the 91 value i just needed one register, but for that five values I need to check the color and get the register with the color according this, if that five equal five values have the color blue that is what I need, but if don't have the blue value search for the green, if don´t have that values search for the black.

Comment: @lau I can use tables definition too

Comment: I've deleted my comment as @GordonLinoff posted an answer. It is actually an elegant way to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by t.type order by v.ord) as seqnum
      from t join
           (values (1, 'blue'), (2, 'green'), (3, 'black'), (4, 'red'), (5, 'white')
           ) v(ord, color)
           on t.color = v.color
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

You can also use a giant `case` expression with `row_number()`, but I think this is easier to follow and maintain.

Comment: Thank you Gordon I think your answer is the most optimal

Answer (score 3):

This could be one approach.

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY type ORDER BY CASE color WHEN 'blue'  THEN 1
                                                                    WHEN 'green' THEN 2
                                                                    WHEN 'black' THEN 3
                                                                    WHEN 'red'   THEN 4
                                                                    WHEN 'white' THEN 5 END) rn
    FROM SomeTable
)
SELECT type, color
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
TYPE
, LAST_VALUE(COLOR) OVER (PARTITION BY COLOR ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
FROM table
```

But SQL Server doesn't guarantee order of `COLOR` name until you have explicit tiebreaker for ORDER BY (instead of `SELECT NULL`), for example, table id.
Hope, you have at least SQL Server 2012, or may be 2008 R2 SP3.